# Not able to create local directory in EMR by user 'livy'

Tags: apache-spark, unix, pyspark, aws-step-functions, livy

I am submitting a **pyspark** job into **EMR** cluster from a **AWS Step Function** through **apache livy**. The pyspark job has **Unix shell** commands being fired.

Within ***test.py***,

```
subprocess.call(' echo $USER', shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=None)
subprocess.call(' mkdir /mnt/data', shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=None)
```

The log file has this output:

```
livy
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/data’: Permission denied
```

The user "livy" is not able to create a directory even with sudo.
I need this script to create a directory, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

User "livy" does not have permission to create directories in EMR.

But to create directories, we can use a bootstrap script. Or else, we can use "Steps" while creating EMR cluster.

While creating directories through bootstrap, sudo user privileges are required.